# How can you change or add an ADMIN user to Firebase

Tags: firebase

I want to give someone admin privileges to change billing info, etc. Can firebase have two admins or switch to another account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have many *collaborators* on a single Firebase app. They have access to the same data as the owner, with the exception of having access to billing information.

There is only one *owner* account per Firebase app. If the app is on a paid plan, the owning account is the one being charged for the service, receiving the billing reminders, and having access to the invoices in the Firebase dashboard. The owner is also the only one who can invite collaborators to the Firebase app.

If you want to change the owner account of a Firebase app, reach out to firebase-support@google.com.